# MSX Job deployment: Not creating job on certain servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

[image]I am deploying a new index maintenance jobs through MSX to about 100 servers, I am in the process of manually checking that each job has been created and I have already discovered that for some currently unknown reason specific servers are not receiving the new MSX job.

Strangely, these servers have been able to successfully disable an older index maintenance job that already exists.

I am wondering if someone can help me identify the reason for this.

On my CMS I have the Server Agent assigned the TargetServerRole in MSDB.

I have noticed in my agent error log, the above information.

Edit: I have since identified that the servers needed resynchronisation, I defected the target (screen capturing existing MSX jobs before doing so), and then rejoined to the master and re-added the MSX jobs - this seemed to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue myself by completing the following tasks:

- In some cases, even though the server existed in the list of registered servers, it was giving me an error that the server wasn't registered, if this occurred, I deleted the server and then re-added it.
- I defected the server and then enlisted it again as a target, but before doing so I would make a record of the existing MSX jobs on the target. After defecting the target loses its MSX jobs, so it was then necessary to re-add them.
- During the enlistment, SQL Server made modifications to the service account that runs the target jobs, and made other changes. This process resolved the issues mentioned above.

There is also the ability to resynchronise jobs on the target servers, but this did not assist in my case.